# Trying to implement calendar using HTML + JS, but it is not displaying, where is my code wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, calendar, rubymine

I am new to RubyMine and javascript.
I'm trying to implement a small calendar on one of my ROR html views. I have used the code found here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/DynamicHTMLCalendar.htm

However, as I am using RubyMine IDE, I have separated the javascript into application.js and the html into home.html (the only view I want the calendar to be seen in). I am not sure if I am allowed to do this but I don't know of any other way... I'm also not sure whether to write in the  and where I should do it

But now it underlines some of the javascript such as ".all" in this, saying "method expression is not of function type":

```
function getObject(obj){
    var theObj;
    if (document.all){
        if(typeof obj == "string"){
            return document.all(obj); <------HERE

        } else {
            return obj.style;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It also will underline variables relating to the html form components saying "unresolved variable" (chooseMonth and chooseYear, both names of select elements of the html form):

```
function populateTable(form){
    var theMonth = form.chooseMonth.selectedIndex; //gets selected month
    var theYear = parseInt(form.chooseYear.options[form.chooseYear.selectedIndex].text); //gets year
...
}
```

as well as here:

```
function setCurrMonth(today){

    document.dateChooser.chooseMonth.selectedIndex = today.getMonth();
}
```

I think it is because of this that when loading the page, only the html elements can be seen, and none of the generated javascript. 
Is this the right way to be going about this? All I want is a small calendar that will allow a user to look at different months. However, I have bigger plans for this calendar as at some point I will need it to display events and be interactive with a user.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add an empty tag <script type="text/javascript"></script> at bottom of your home.html(.erb) and check your home page have extension html.erb.

Comment: that has not fixed my problem. Why can my javascript not automatically find an html element by name if it's already connected to it? Do I have to use JQuery?

Comment: Using Development tools (Firebug on Firefox i.e.) you can verify run-time your javascript and check if it has been well charged. Try to move js code directly in home.html.erb ... maybe you have some stupid error in your code.